# Free-throw lines length

Tags: rules, basketball, fiba

Art. 2.4.3 of the [FIBA official rules](http://www.fiba.basketball/OBR2017/Final.pdf) (approved 4th July 2017) says that

> The free-throw line shall be drawn parallel to each endline. It shall
>   have its furthest edge 5.80 m from the inner edge of the endline and
>   shall be 3.60 m long

But in Diagram 2 of the same rules, the free-throw line is 4.9 m long (and not 3.6)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That 4.9 m line in Diagram 2 is the *extended* free-throw line, used for defining the restricted area. The centre 3.6 m of that line, where it joins the free-throw semi-circle, is the free-throw line itself. When taking a free throw, a player must

> Take a position behind the free-throw line and inside the semi-circle.

(Art 43.2.3). If they took a position behind either of the 0.65 m extensions of the free-throw line, they would be in an incorrect position.